# Find if records present in DataTable

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application to get data from SQL DB in a data table (along with column header) as below.

```
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       dt = GetANumber();
```

I have to execute another function based on the results ( not column) in the DataTable.

That is :

```
    If( there is result returns from the DataTable)
    {
       Call another function 
    }
```

How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Side-note: you don't need to initialize the `DataTable` if you'll overwrite it in the next line with a different instance. It's better to usen `DataTable dt = GetANumber()` then. If `GetABumber` will return null you could not prevent that with your first initialization anyway. You have to handle that afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean this `DataTable` class, in the `System.Data` namespace:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-5.0

Then you can cast it to an `IEnumerable` using the `ToEnumerable()` extension method in `System.Data`.

Then, you can see if there are any rows in the table using the Linq extension method `Any()`

In your `using` statements:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
```

Then in your method:

```
  if(yourDataTable.AsEnumerable().Rows.Any())
    {
       // Call your other function 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- `dt.Rows.Count != 0` or (with `using System.Linq`)
- `dt.AsEnumerable().Any()` or
- `dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Any()`